# Apache Spark uses only one core from 8 cores available in 4 vCPU on the machine

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ecs

I start Apache Spark Worker on AWS Fargate instance with 4 vCPU * 2 cores in each:

```
processor : 0
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
cpu MHz : 1604.990
physical id : 0
siblings : 4
core id : 0
cpu cores : 2

processor : 1
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
cpu MHz : 1604.990
physical id : 0
siblings : 4
core id : 1
cpu cores : 2

processor : 2
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
cpu MHz : 1604.990
physical id : 0
siblings : 4
core id : 0
cpu cores : 2

processor : 3
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
cpu MHz : 1604.990
physical id : 0
siblings : 4
core id : 1
cpu cores : 2
```

But the Worker start only with one core:

```
INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker <..IP..>:8881 with 1 cores, 28.9 GiB RAM
```

By default Apache Spark should use 0.8*[number of cores], right?

My environment. Apache Spark 3.0.2 in Standalone mode. One Master and a number of Workers on different machines. All runs in Docker containers in Amazon ECS cluster, FARGATE mode.

Because this is inside Docker container I start Spark like that:

```
bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker ${SPARK_MASTER_URL}
```

There is no specific settings for Spark CPU usage in Spark config or env vars.

Comment: 4 vCPUs means 4 total cores, not 4 physical cores with hyperthreading for a total of 8. The output of `/proc/cpuinfo` is also telling you that if you look at the `core_id` of each. That aside, how are you seeing that it's only using 1 core?

Comment: just by this log line
INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker <..IP..>:8881 with 1 cores, 28.9 GiB RAM

Comment: I also tried to set SPARK_WORKER_CORES but it's more strange - I even can set it to 30 and after that I see in logs: Starting Spark worker .. with 30 cores 8-)

Comment: What makes you think the default should be 0.8 x the number of available cores and not just 1?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html
...Total CPU cores to allow Spark applications to use on the machine (default: all available); only on worker..
also if I do not specify cores manually I see on :8080 page all workers with just one core available